# Render MarkerClusterer with Custom Marker and Dynamic location

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, markerclusterer

I have a issue when rendering markers and clustering them. When i fetch location data list from api completely, map doesn't re-render marker.

When i use custom marker child component, that can re-render map when api is fetch completely. But I can't Clustering these custom marker.

As i know that onGoogleApiLoaded just called once times at the first render so now I have no solution to solve this issue.

Here my code below. Thanks for any help.

```
  const get_list_unit_location = useCallback(() => {
    if (units.length) {
      const listLocation = [];
      units.forEach((unit) => {
        if (unit.lat && unit.lng) {
          listLocation.push({
            lat: unit.lat,
            lng: unit.lng,
            subUnitQuantity: unit.sub_units.length,
          });
        }
      });
      setUnitLocations(listLocation);
    }
  }, [units]);

  useEffect(() => {
    get_list_unit_location();
  }, [get_list_unit_location]);

  const setGoogleMapRef = useCallback(
    (map, maps) => {
      if (unitLocations.length) {
        const markers = unitLocations.map((location) => {
          return new maps.Marker({ position: location, map });
        });
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
        const markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer({ map, markers });
      }
    },
    [unitLocations]
  );

<GoogleMapReact
          bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY }}
          defaultCenter={center}
          defaultZoom={zoom}
          options={{
            fullscreenControl: false,
            zoomControl: false,
          }}
          yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals
          onGoogleApiLoaded={({ map, maps }) => setGoogleMapRef(map, maps)}
        >
          {unitLocations.map((location) => (
            // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-key
            <Marker
              lat={location.lat}
              lng={location.lng}
              text={location.subUnitQuantity}
            />
          ))}
        </GoogleMapReact>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to have `setGoogleMapRef` do nothing more than store `map` and `maps` into some state, and then have a separate `useEffect` that creates the `MarkerClusterer`. This will ensure that the clusterer isn't created until both map and data are loaded (and will be recreated if the data changes.) Something like:

```
const [ map, setMap ] = useState();
const [ maps, setMaps ] = useState();

const setGoogleMapRef = useCallback((map, maps) => {
    setMap(map);
    setMaps(maps);
}, [ setMap, setMaps ]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (unitLocations.length && map && maps) {
        // create markers and clusterer
    }
}, [ unitLocations, map, maps]);
```

Alternatively, if you're willing to look at a different package, `@react-google-maps/api` has a component for the clusterer as well as the map, marker, etc:

```
<GoogleMap ...>
    <MarkerClusterer ...>
        {clusterer => unitLocations.map((location, index) => {
           <Marker position={location} clusterer={clusterer}/>
        }
    </MarkerClusterer>
</GoogleMap >
```